# JS wont set style margin inside another div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using bootstrap and my element for which I need set style is inside bootsrap col-sm-6 div element. I don't know why but my script is not working.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 spacer1">
//Objects
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementByClassName('spacer1').style.padding = "50px 50px";
</script>
```

My script is placed under my element so I think it is being executed after this element is loaded. I tried everything, but I cant get this to work.
Yes, I could just write this to css file, but I need to change this dynamically for each div. What is wrong here?

**EDIT**
If this return nodelist, how to select it? I don know anything about this...

**Thank you very much, I have fixed everything :)**

Comment: You are missing an `s` in function name. `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a nodelist. First select a node from this list then apply style properties on it.

Comment: OP uses `getElementByClassName` (singular) which doesn't exist at all, and should throw an error which can be seen in the console in the browser. So, @supercoder, did you get that error? You would indeed need to use the right function here. Maybe you can switch to `querySelector`, which does return a single node, or `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll` if you need to (potentially) target multiple nodes.

Comment: By the way why you decided to choose JS instead of CSS for adding styles? I don't see any event handler here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements, so you need to select the first element.

Try

```
document.getElementsByClassName('spacer1')[0].style.padding = "50px 50px";
```

Comment: getElementByClassName doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Indeed, it's getElementsByClassName('spacer1')[0], it's a plural, not a singular.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('spacer1')[0].style.padding = "50px 50px";`

`getElementByClassName` does not exist.

You can use `getElementsByClassName` and select the first element in the nodeList.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)